# SQL Query datetime issue

Tags: sql-server

I have a query on SQL Server that's finding wrong results based on a datetime condition.

```
SET LANGUAGE Português

select distinct
       CONVERT(varchar(10), DATENAME(MONTH, i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), 
       DATENAME(YEAR,i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento)) AS Periodo,
       i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento,
       i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_limite_envio_nf,
       i9_parcelaBase.i9_status_atual,
       i9_processo_statusBase.i9_status, 
       i9_processo_statusBase.i9_name
      --i9_nota_fiscalBase.i9_nota_fiscalid as ID
from  i9_parcelaBase 
  left join i9_processo_statusBase 
    on i9_parcelaBase.i9_status_atual = i9_processo_statusBase.i9_processo_statusId
where  i9_processo_statusBase.i9_entidade = 100000002 
and    i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento between CONVERT(varchar(10),  year(getdate())-1) + '-' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),  month(getdate())+1) + '-1'   
                                             and CONVERT(varchar(10),  year(getdate())) + '-' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),  month(getdate())) + '-1'
order by i9_data_vencimento asc
```

Basically, Month that's receiving data without '0' before (when necessary).

Sample:
Actual return: '2017-6-1'
Expected return '2017-06-01'

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: *Don't* convert dates to strings. Compare dates to dates directly. Dates have no format, they are binary values, so there is no reason to conver them to strings. If you store dates as strings, you have a serious design bug.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? SQL Server 2014 introduced the `FORMAT` function that allows you to use .NET format strings. Another option is to format only on the client side. It's a lot easier to specify a format string on a grid or report than work around string formatting limitations. SQL, the language, isn't meant for string manipulations

Comment: If you must convert dates to strings, use the CONVERT() function and specify a format. In this case, your format should probably be 120 or 121, so: `... between CONVERT(varchar(7),  getdate(), 120) + '-01' AND...`

Comment: I Changed my 'where" definition from `i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento between CONVERT(varchar(10),  year(getdate())-1) + '-' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),  month(getdate())+1) + '-1'   
                                             and CONVERT(varchar(10),  year(getdate())) + '-' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),  month(getdate())) + '-1'` to `i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento between DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-11,0)) and DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))` and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your query, i9_data_vencimento is expected to end with just -1, not -01. You can cast the string into a date, then recast it back as a string as a way to format it:

```
select distinct
       CONVERT(varchar(10), DATENAME(MONTH, i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(10), 
       DATENAME(YEAR,i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento)) AS Periodo,
       CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), CONVERT( DATETIME, i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento ), 120 ) AS i9_data_vencimento,
        :
        :
```

Also, considering that i9_data_vencimento is just a string, and assuming it always ends with '1' in the format 'yyyy-mm-1', you could use a LEFT function to strip off the last character and replace it with '01':

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       :
       LEFT(i9_parcelaBase.i9_data_vencimento, 8) + '01' AS i9_data_vencimento,
       :
```

Comment: The best solution, though, is as Panagiotis Kanavos suggested - use dates until it's necessary to convert them to strings. Preferably in the UI code or at the Endpoint to the UI.